# Salesforce DX Use Case

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

We are a small team of three members and planning to implement SFDX in our project, I have some questions regarding the same.

1. Is there any additional cost involved on sfdx? I believe no, but not able to find any supporting document regarding the same.
2. Based on the documents available online, it seems we still need to use Version Control like Bitbucket, GitHub and Continious Integration tool like Jenkins, Bamboo with sfdx. What if we don't want to use Version Control, will it still be beneficial for us? If yes, how we can leverage the sfdx without VC.

Answer (score 5):

At a small scale, there are no costs involved. But be aware that the number of [Scratch Orgs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs.htm) you can have varies with the edition of the org that you install the Dev Hub in:

```
Edition                     Active Scratch Org Allocation   Daily Scratch Org Allocation
Developer Edition or trial  3                               6
Enterprise Edition          40                              80
Unlimited Edition           100                             200
Performance Edition         100                             200
```

If you already have an Enterprise Edition org you are all set; if not you should consider purchasing one.

Do consider how much the time of your three people is worth. Being able to share your work easily, and being protected from accidental overwrites via version control will in the medium term save you money; subscriptions to e.g. GitHub are not expensive. Unless the three of you are each working on entirely unrelated things, not having version control to synchronize your changes would result in a lot of manual copying.

Unless this is a very short "one-off" project, I would recommend following the documented processes rather than trying to roll your own. The newer Git, SFDX, Scratch Org, VSCode approach is a way more productive (and enjoyable) way to work than using the older tools. And the skills you pick up along the way will have lasting value.

Comment: What about "Unlocked" packages? is it more useful then Ant based deployment and do we also need Version Control for Unlocked packages?

Comment: @salesforceDeveloper Not something I have used. If the 3 people are working on entirely separate things then the version control is less important.

Answer (score 3):

1) No, there isn't.

2) You are able to do the following

- get rid of ant scripts
- adopt a better testing approach with scratch orgs
- adopt "unlocked" package as the next stage of evolution of standard packages
- use apex debugging, lightning linter and other programmers stuff with VS code extensions
- write your own sfdx extensions to configure your own dev environment for your own needs
- get rid of testing samples of code in dev console in UI as  you are able to perform soql queries and "execute anonymous windows" via CLI
- ETC.

Hope, I was helpful

Answer (score 0):

1. no  additional cost
2. using version control is the whole point of sfdx, so if you want to work like in 2005 with everyone updating everything without tracking, this is pointless to use sfdx :)